# Automatically render foreign key in the hidden form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

Why isn't Ruby on Rails smart enough to guess render foreign key in the hidden field? How can I avoid to render hidden field manually [like this](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/app/views/users/_follow.html.erb#L3)?

Answer (score 1):

It's because keeping a foreign key in a hidden field in a form is not quite smart. Cause then a user can alter that foreign key and for example send a comment to a post that he is blocked from. 
It's much better to get that foreign key from the url params or in any other way on the server side.